# Good design for delegating template-member functionality

Tags: c++, templates, encapsulation

I am having trouble in finding simple and elegant design for the following scenario. Class `Worker` uses template class `Helper` to do some work. In the simple scenario it looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Helper {
  public:
    void Help(T data) : m_data(data) {} //NOTICE: Copy
    T const& Data() const { return m_data; }

    T m_data;
}

class SimpleWorker {
  public:
    SimpleWorker() : m_helper(SimpleData()) {} // non-temp used in reality
    void DoWork()
    {
        m_helper.help();
    }        

    Helper<SimpleData> m_helper;
}
```

Things get complicated for me when the template argument is more complex and is of the same business domain of the worker. The worker needs to use the helper but it would also need to call some methods on the data object that the helper doesn't even know about (in this design). Something like:

```
template<typename T>
class Helper {
  public:
    Helper(T data) : m_data(data) {} //NOTICE: Copy
    T const& Data() const { return m_data; }

    T m_data;
}

class ComplexWorker {
  public:
    ComplexWorker() : m_helper(ComplexData()) {} // non-temp used in reality

    void DoWork()
    {
        m_helper.help();
        m_helper.GetData().DoSomethingComplexNotConst(); // <-------------
    }    

    Helper<ComplexData> m_helper;    
}
```

The obvious problem is that I can't call not const function on `Data()` result. Making `Data()` non-const seems like a bad idea as `Helper` is used in different contexts as well. My goal is to find an elegant way to alter `ComplexData` using its member functions from `ComplexWorker`
The `ComplexData` needs to be altered in the first place so that `Helper` can continue working with the altered data.

**EDIT:** Changed `Helper` construction to copy the provided data to better resemble actual flow

Comment: How do you initialize m_helper? This should be done via ComplexWorker, right? Then ComplexWorker can do the complex operation on the data first and then initialize the helper with the modified, data. Isn't doing that way simple?

Comment: At the moment, `m_helper` is initialized by `ComplexWorker` and then copied in the `Helper` constructor. I didn't express it in the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's best to let `Helper` have only static functions, not maintaing state (as you create temporary `ComplexData()` in `ComplexWorker` in your own code). Pass the data by reference or const-reference depending on whether you need to modify or not.

```
// primary template
template<typename T>
class Helper {
public:
    static void help(T const& data) const {} // non-modifying
};

// specialization for ComplexData
template<>
class Helper<ComplexData> {
public:
    static void help(ComplexData const& data) const { } // non-modifying

    static void DoSomethingComplexNotConst(ComplexData& data) // modifying
    {
         // your implementation here
    }
};

class ComplexWorker {
public: 
    ComplexWorker() : m_data(ComplexData()) {} // create new data

    void DoWork()
    {
        Helper<ComplexData>::help(m_data);
        Helper<ComplexData>::DoSomethingComplexNotConst(m_data); // <--- now no problem
    }

   private:
       ComplexData m_data;         
};
```

Note that I made a **template specialization** for the `ComplexData`. There is some code duplication in `help()` but you can easily extract this into a common non-member helper function.

Comment: Notice that `m_data` is of template type `T`. I can't simply add the manipulators to `Helper` as it knows nothing of `T` besides the minimum it needs to function. I could add methods using partial specialization. However, delegating these manipulators seems cumbersome and it complicates the solution (multiple `Data` types and manipulators).

Comment: Last comment was written before the edit. Though the last part still holds.

Comment: @Albert If you need to do different stuff for different `Data` types, then there is no way around to writing several specializations. Common code can always be refactored into non-member functions or other classes. My main point is to encapsulate complex algorithms and never to expose raw data through a reference or a pointer.

Comment: I get it, and totally agree. But the "dirty" solution, exposing `m_data` is much more scale-able and easier to maintain. Another direction I thought about is sharing `Data` between `Helper` and `Worker` so both have independent access to it.

Comment: @Albert No, exposing data is completely unmaintainable because you expose the implementation to all clients! Effectively, the data format is now part of the interface. Clients will start to rely on that and you can never change it again without breaking stuff. Encapsulation into building blocks is much more maintainable and scalable.

Comment: Again agreed. This is why I don't do it. But, your proposed solution adds much code and creates coupling between `ComplexData` which requires updating `Helper<T>` every time new functionality is added to `ComplexData`. Notice, however, that `ComplexWroker` is aware of `ComplexData` interface. They both come from the same business domain and `ComplexData` is even constructed by `ComplexWorker` (Notice I edited the question)

Comment: @Albert The code I added is providing new functionality, and the old code is not affected by it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15334/discussion-between-albert-and-rhalbersma)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that it depends on what `Helper` is actually doing. Your example just gives a constructor and an accessor but I doubt that is all it does in practice.

Have you considered simply using inheritance? Your `Helper` template would then look like this:

```
template<typename T>
class Helper : public T {
    Helper(T data) : T(data) {}
    void Help() {};
}
```

In this case you could use the `Helper<ComplexData>` object directly in an 'is-a' relationship:

```
class ComplexWorker {
    Helper<ComplexData> m_helper;

    void DoWork()
    {
        m_helper.help();
        m_helper.DoSomethingComplexNotConst();
    }        
}
```

Comment: Using inheritance as an implementation device is generally bad advice. What if the OP needs two instances of `T`? That path leads into the realm of multiple inheritance and the dreaded diamond problem.

Comment: I think it would be wrong. `Helper` is not `Data 
(T)` - logically speaking. As `Helper` is used in other contexts as well I feel it would be an abuse. The real classes are somehow similar to `Helper <-> Serializer` and Data is Data.

Comment: @Albert: Well, as I mentioned, it really depends on what `Helper` is actually going. If `Helper<ComplexData>` *could* be viewed as extending `ComplexData` with an 'is-a' relationship then it would be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not refer to the realization of the Container part in STL. An overload of the Data() function may achieve a ballance between safty and elegance.

```
template <typename T>
class Helper {
public:
    Helper(T data) : m_data(data) {} //NOTICE: Copy
    T const& Data() const { return m_data; }
    T& Data() {return m_data; }
private:
    T m_data;
}

class ComplexWorker {
public:
    ComplexWorker() : m_helper(ComplexData()) {} // non-temp used in reality

    void DoWork()
    {
        m_helper.help();
        ComplexData &cd1 = m_helper.Data();
        cd1.QuerySth();
        const ComplexData &cd2 = m_helper.Data();
        cd2.ModifySth();
    }    
private:
    Helper<ComplexData> m_helper;    
}
```

Comment: You suggest to expose `m_helper`. I would like to avoid it. I also believe that the `const` overload mostly exists for `const m_helper' and not as you demonstrated. A cast from non-const to const always exists.